# How to exclude "My Sites" from SharePoint 2013 search that retrieves sites

Tags: search, search-results

I am using search to find sites and then sub-sites/webs for a given user.  Currently, the search is returning all users personal/My Sites and I don't want these in the results.  Is there a way change the search query to exclude "My Sites" in the results?  I need a generic solution so I can't add/modify query rules etc.  I need it to work out-of-the-box.

I am using REST API and my current query looks like this:

```
../query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'&selectproperties='SiteId,Path,Title'&rowlimit=100&trimduplicates=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `NOT Path: http://mysite/*` to your query where you use your My Site host address.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter them out by using WebTemplate property like this:

```
(NOT WebTemplate:SPSPERS)
```

Tested in SP2016.